# PHP GD turn background into transparent or alpha

Tags: php, gd

[image]

I have an jpeg image, I want to use php GD to create 2 boxs.

1. left box will remove background and set transparent
2. Right box will set rgba - alpha 80%;

and save it in png transparance

I have try imagesetpixel, but its not transparent,

I also try imagecolortransparent

```
$transparentcolour = imagecolorallocate($im, 40,220,1);
imagecolortransparent($image, $transparentcolour);
```

but this will turn everything into transparent in this color.

anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight transparent is easy:

1. Disable alpha blending
2. Allocate a colour with alpha - personally I use `(255,0,255,127)` because magenta is the "standard" transparent colour when working with game sprites, so I just sort of stuck with it
3. Draw the rectangle

The result will be a block of transparency.

Function reference: [`imagealphablending`](http://php.net/imagealphablending), [`imagecolorallocatealpha`](http://php.net/imagecolorallocatealpha), [`imagefilledrectangle`](http://php.net/imagefilledrectangle)

---

The "fade by 80%" thing will be trickier.

1. Disable alpha blending
2. For each `(x,y)` in the rectangle... (ie. two nested `for` loops)

   1. Get the colour of that pixel (`imagecolorat` and `imagecolorsforindex` should help)
   2. Multiply `$color['alpha']` by `0.2` for an 80% fade
   3. Allocate a new colour with the same `RGB` as the source, but with the new `A` value
   4. Draw the pixel

The result will be a block of 80%-faded-to-transparent pixels.

Function reference: [`imagealphablending`](http://php.net/imagealphablending), [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/imagecolorat), [`imagecolorsforindex`](http://php.net/imagecolorsforindex), [`imagecolorallocatealpha`](http://php.net/imagecolorallocatealpha), [`imagesetpixel`](http://php.net/imagesetpixel)

Comment: for option 2: simpler way is to create a new rectangle image, flood with an 80% transparent color, then copymerge at the appropriate coordinates

Comment: @MarcB Does that work? I thought copymerge would... oooohh, but with alpha blending off... right?